# Facebook app friends users posts don't appear on my news feed

Tags: facebook, post, feed

I built a Facebook app which allows users to post some news to their news feed from my website. I use Facebook Connect and the Facebook JS library.

When a friend of mine (Facebook friend) posts something to his news feed from my website using my Facebook app, I don't see it in my news feed. His other friends see it. Is it because I am the developer of the app and the posts from my Facebook app get filtered in some ways. It should not though.

Anyone is having the same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons you wouldn't see it, none of which have to do with being the developer of the app.

1. You may have already blocked your friend from appearing in your feed.
2. You may have already blocked your own application accidentally from appearing in your feed.
3. You may not be looking at the "most recent" posts, you may be looking at "top news", which doesn't gaurantee to show every post.

Go visit your friend's profile, if you see the item on his wall, it was posted successfully. There is nothing you can do programatically to change this.

Comment: No to 1, 2 and 3. I checked all settings of my Facebook account and of my Facebook app. I see the post on my Friend's feed by not on mine.

Comment: Do you mean that you see it on his **wall** but not on your **feed**? Because you aren't supposed to see it on your **wall**.

Comment: Correct. I see it on his wall but no on my feed even if he is my friend. This issue only happens to posts from my Facebook app.